# Adding a Remote to a Git Repo Owned by Someone Else

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

Not sure if this is the right place to be asking this, and quite possibly incredibly simple or dumb.

A company has a private GitHub repository which they have granted me access to, so that I may pull the site to my local machine make changes and push back to their GitHub account where they can they push to the live site. No problems there.

However, after pulling the site locally and making changes and testing locally, I'd like to push the site to a staging server of my own for them to view, before pushing it back to their github account.

Would I need them to add that remote since they own the private repo, or as long as I have push access do I have access to add a new remote?

I may be thinking about this question all wrong, so any quick guidance in the right direction would be very helpful. Or let me know if this is better suited for a different SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once cloned locally, nothing prevents you to push that repo to another server (different from GitHub).

```
git remote add staging /url/to/staging/bare/repo
```

It is up to you to make manage the access to that staging server though, making sure that anyone isn't able to clone it.

Comment: Great, that's what I was hoping, but wasn't sure if there was something I was missing and wanted to make sure that wouldn't interfere with the companies existing remotes. Thanks!